# Divergence theorem for Sobolev functions on whole space

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, divergence-theorem

Let $u_1, \dots, u_d, w \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d).$ We set $u:=(u_1, \dots, u_d)^{\top}.$
Is the following identity true for the whole space? (If we assume the divergence theorem for Sobolev functions on bounded smooth-boundary sets.)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{div}(u)w \, \mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} u^{\top} \nabla w \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
I think so because:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{div}(u)w \, dx &= \lim\limits_{R \to +\infty} \int_{B_R(0)} \mathrm{div}(u)w \, dx = \lim\limits_{R \to +\infty} \left[-\int_{B_R(0)} u^{\top} \nabla w \, dx + \int_{\partial B_R(0)}  (u^{\top} n) w\, ds \right] \\
&= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} u^{\top} \nabla w \, dx + \lim\limits_{R \to +\infty} \int_{\partial B_R(0)}  (u^{\top} n) w\, ds.
\end{align*}

In order for the boundary integral to vanish, the corresponding integrand must converge to $0$ fast enough. Adequate conditions must be placed on the functions $u$ and $v$ for this. A sufficient condition would be $|u(x)||v(x)| \in o(\Vert x \Vert^{1-d})$ for $\Vert x \Vert \to + \infty,$ because for the $d$-dimensional volume of the unit sphere $\mathrm{vol}_d( \partial B_R(0)) = c_d R^{d-1}$ (the real constant $c_d > 0$ depends only on the dimension $d \in \mathbb{N}$), this is certainly for Schwartz -Functions $u,v \in \mathcal{S}({\mathbb{R}^d})$ fulfilled. However, we are dealing with Sobolev functions, fortunately the boundary integral also vanishes if $u,v \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ holds, since in this case we could argue by density of the Schwartz space in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Could anyone confirm this?

Comment: My guess is yes: First consider the case $u,w\in C_c^\infty$, and then argue by density (since both integrals will be controlled by products of the $H^1$ norms of $u$ and $w$.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious for smooth functions with compact support $C_c^{\infty}$, but can't we look at functions from Schwartz space right away? It should be the same result.

Comment: yes that's right, Schwartz functions have sufficient decay to make the boundary terms disappear (they in fact vanish much more rapidly than the mere polynomial growth of the surface area). So, now that you have the formula for Schwartz functions, you can use density to argue for all $u,v$ in the $H^1$ Sobolev space. Note that you don't have to a-priori assume anything about divergence theorem for Sobolev functions. You can prove the identity in question for Schwartz functions first using their smoothness and decay, Then afterwards, invoke density. This is much cleaner I think.

Comment: I see, thanks. And with the same argument we would get
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{div}(u) \, dx = 0$$ for $u \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^d).$
If I understood that right.